# create different list of dicts from master list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary as following:-

```
listDict =[{'name':'A',
        'fun':'funA', 
        'childs':[{'name':'B',
                   'fun':'funB', 
                   'childs':[{ 'name':'D',
                               'fun':'funD'}]}, 
                  {'name':'C',
                   'fun':'funC', 
                   'childs':[{ 'name':'E',
                               'fun':'funE'},
                             { 'name':'F',
                               'fun':'funF'},
                             { 'name':'G',
                               'fun':'funG',
                               'childs' :[{ 'name':'H',
                                            'fun':'funH'}]}]}]}, 
       {'name':'Z',
        'fun':'funZ'}]
```

I wanted to create three list of dict from this :-
1. With no child and no parent

```
lod1 = [{'name':'Z'
         'fun':'funZ'}]
```

2.with no child but having parent and parent as key:-

```
`lod2 = [{'B':[{ 'name':'D',
                 'fun':'funD'}]},
        {'C':[{'name':'E',
               'fun':'funE'},
              {'name':'F',
               'fun':'funF'}]},
        {'G':[{ 'name':'H',
                'fun':'funH'}]
        }]`
```

3.with only parent child as a flat list with parent as key :-

```
lod3 = [{'A': [{ 'name':'B',
                 'fun':'funB'},
               {'name':'C',
               'fun':'funC'}]},
        {'C': [{'name':'G',
                'fun':'funG'}]
        }]
```

Is there any possible way to do this with or without recursion. The purpose of this division is that I am trying to create a flat class structure, where are all nodes in category 1 (no child and parent) are added as a function of final class. All nodes with no child but having parent (category 2) are added as a function of respective parent class. And remaining parent child (category 3) will be created as classes with childs having instance of parent.

Comment: Could you give a more general description of what you're trying to accomplish? All parent nodes in separate variables, and all child nodes combined in other variables? What's the logic of the numbering of new variables?

Comment: @klasske I am trying to create a flat class structure, where are all nodes in category 1 (no child and parent) are added as a function of final class. All nodes with no child but having parent (category 2) are added as a function of respective parent class. And remaining parent child (category 3) will be created as classes with childs having instance of parent.

Comment: Put that description in your question.

Comment: Could you please check the listDict example you gave: a copy/paste in my Python editor returns me errors... So your example may be broken.

Comment: @Simsom - Yes, there were some parenthesis missing. I have corrected that and I really apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a task for which the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is appropriate. You have a tree like structure and you wish to traverse it, accumulating the three different sets of information.

To implement this well, you should separate the traversal of the structure from the data collection. In that way you only need to define the different forms of data collection rather than reimplemeting the visitor each time. So lets start with that.

The visitor will take a dictionary, consider it, and will visit all of the dictionaries in the `childs` list (you may wish to rename this to *children*).

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class DictionaryVisitor(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def visit(self, node, parents, result):
        """ This inspects the current node and
            accumulates any data into result """
        pass  # Implement this in the subclasses

    def accept(self, node, parents, result):
        """ This tests if the node should be traversed. This is an efficiency
            improvement to prevent traversing lots of nodes that you have no
            interest in """
        return True

    def traverse(self, node, parents, result):
        """ This traverses the dictionary, visiting each node in turn """
        if not self.accept(node, parents, result):
            return

        self.visit(node, parents, result)
        if 'childs' in node:
            for child in node['childs']:
                self.traverse(child, parents + [node], result)

    def start(self, dict_list):  # bad method name
        """ This just handles the parents and result argument of traverse """
        # Assuming that result is always a list is not normally appropriate
        result = []
        for node in dict_list:
            self.traverse(node, [], result)
        return result
```

You can then implement the different required outputs as subclasses of this abstract base class:

```
class ParentlessChildlessVisitor(DictionaryVisitor):
    def visit(self, node, parents, result):
        """ Collect the nodes that have no parents or children """
        # parent filtering is performed in accept
        if 'childs' not in node:
            result.append(node)

    def accept(self, nodes, parents, result):
        """ Reject all nodes with parents """
        return not parents
```

Then you can call it:

```
visitor = ParentlessChildlessVisitor()
results = visitor.start(data)
print results
# prints [{'fun': 'funZ', 'name': 'Z'}]
```

The next one:

```
class ChildlessChildVisitor(DictionaryVisitor):
    def visit(self, node, parents, result):
        """ Collect the nodes that have parents but no children """
        if parents and 'childs' not in node:
            # slightly odd data structure here, a list of dicts where the only
            # dict key is unique. It would be better to be a plain dict, which
            # is what is done here:
            result[parents[-1]['name']].append(node)

    def start(self, dict_list):
        """ This just handles the parents and result argument of traverse """
        # Here it is much better to have a dict as the result.
        # This is an example of why wrapping all this logic in the start method
        # is not normally appropriate.
        result = defaultdict(list)
        for node in dict_list:
            self.traverse(node, [], result)
        return result

visitor = ChildlessChildVisitor()
results = visitor.start(listDict)
print dict(results)
# prints {'C': [{'fun': 'funE', 'name': 'E'}, {'fun': 'funF', 'name': 'F'}], 'B': [{'fun': 'funD', 'name': 'D'}], 'G': [{'fun': 'funH', 'name': 'H'}]}
```

It is not entirely clear to me what you want to collect with the last example so you will have to handle that one yourself.

Comment: @Mattew thanks and for the third one , I have a way. First I remove all the dicts fron the list of type 1. Then I recursively check if there is any child and if true then add that to a flat list as:- def _recursiveSearchForGroups(data_list, flat_list):
    for elem in data_list:
        if elem.has_key('childs'):
            flat_list.append(elem)
            _recursiveSearchForGroups(elem['childs'], flat_list)

Comment: That sound like a search that can be defined as a visitor, like the others. I think your code would be better if you did it in a way consistent with the others. If you change the visit condition to `parents and 'childs' in node` it should do what you describe. You will need to copy the current node and remove the `childs` key before adding to `result` to get the output you provided in your question.